# Merge one column based on matches of another in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In column E I am trying to merge column D into one the next cell E with a "/" in between each new cells value if column B contains a match. If there is no match then just take the value from column D. If you look at end goal it will explain a bit better. I tried if(Match( but that doesn't seem to work.  Thanks all!

```
Explanation ProductID   Qty Location Notes  (END GOAL)
RMA-1234    SKU1         1      A1A1         A1A1
RMA-7444    SKU2         1      A1A2         A1A2
RMA-9837    KSC U        1      A1A6         A1A6/A1A7/A1A8
RMA-5837    KSC U        1      A1A7         A1A6/A1A7/A1A8
RMA-6342    KSC U        1      A1A8         A1A6/A1A7/A1A8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use VBA and loop through all the cells in column b when there is a match until there is no match then concatenate the values with a slash in between.

Ex.

```
   Dim tempHolder as String
   For Each cell In yourWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B6")
       If tempHolder == cell.Value Then
              'write your value and a "/" to the adjacent cell if there is a match to previous
       Else if tempHolder == ""
              'write singular values to adjacent cell
       End If
       tempHolder = cell.Value
   Next cell
```

This is just a sample.  If you use it you'll have to tweak it a bit for your application and write the code that inserts your concatenated values in the adjacent cells.

Answer (score 0):

With some ingenuity, you can use built-in Excel formulas to accomplish this.

Here is the worksheet with each step broken out:

[image]

1. Make sure you data is sorted by `ProductID`
2. Create Full List formula: `=IF(B1=B2,E1&"/"&D2,D2)`
3. Count Instances formula: `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,B2)`
4. Find First Instance formula: `=MATCH(B2,$B$2:$B$11,0)`
5. Full List with Slash formula: `=OFFSET($B$1,G2+F2-1,3)`

Drag all these formulas down from row 2 to the end of your dataset.

I broke the steps out so you can understand more easily. However, you can write this all in two columns as well. The Create Full List Column and another column with the following formula (which joins the last four columns in my example together): `=OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(B2,$B$2:$B$11,0)+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,B2)-1,3)`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, the thing is I ideally would want to do this without sorting since I know this is a step that someone who doesn't understand excel would overlook. Ideally i'd have the grouped and / list in sheet 2 so that the person can just copy and paste sheet into new excel file save and import it into our system, and use this as a template file.

Comment: @user1771351 - is sorting really that difficult to do as 1 step in the process? I.E. - 1) Copy Data In 2) sort 3) fill down formulas. If you instruct them clearly, they can do it :)

Comment: Do it in VBA if you have users you are worried about following instructions.  My answer above shows how.  @Scott Holtzmans answer is excellent but you can further automate it on workbook load to sort and provide the concatenated values automatically.  If the data gets inserted after the sheet is opened you can put a trigger in your code that will fire when someone pastes values to the sheet. Or just add a button to the sheet to process once the user has satisfactorily copied all data to it. 

VBA is excellent to automate tasks within Office products so it may work very will for your situation.